# Evaluating limits within limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Suppose $f(h)$ is a function in the variable $h$ such that the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)}{h}$ is known to exist. Then does the following relation hold?

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$$

Intuitively this seems to make sense to me but I am unable to come up with a rigorous mathematical proof to either prove or disprove this. Can someone tell me if this is a valid equation and please justify it with a proof?

Comment: The expression does not make much sense, where do you see that?

Comment: The left hand side makes no sense.  Once the first limit has been done there is NO h in the expression.

Comment: @user247327 That is totally irrelevant. $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}}$ makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to write

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lim_{t\to 0}f(t)}{h}$ instead of $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\lim_{h\to 0}f(h)}{h}.$

Inorder to answer your question look at $f(x)=x.$